# Python selenium - get element by its xPath and access it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am using Python and Selenium to scrape a webpage, in some cases, I can't get it to work.

I would like to access the element with text 'PInt', which is the second link in the below code.
The xPath for it (copied from Developer console) is: ***//*[@id="submenu1"]/a[2]**

```
      <div id="divTest" onscroll="SetDivPosition();" style="height: 861px;">
            <div class="menuTitle" id="title1">
                <a href="#" onclick="toggle(1);"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subtitle" id="submenu1">    
                <img src="images/spacer.gif" border="0" width="2px" height="12px">
                <a href="#" class="NormalBlueSmall" onclick="clickItem('area/search/mov/mov2','mov');">Mov</a><br>
                <img src="images/spacer.gif" border="0" width="2px" height="12px">
                <a href="#" class="NormalBlueSmall" onclick="clickItem('area/con/ExtInt/extInt','pIint');">PInt</a><br>
                <img src="images/spacer.gif" border="0" width="2px" height="12px">
                <a href="#" class="NormalBlueSmall" onclick="clickItem('GoToNew.asp?link=asw_cnt/SmanSwif.aspx','SMAN/SWIF');">SWAM / SWIF</a><br>
            </div>
...
```

A snippet of my code is:

```
try:
    res = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('PInt')
    print("res1:{}".format(res))

    res = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="submenu1"]/a[3]')
    print("res:{} type[0]:{}".format(res,res[0]))
    itm1 = res[0]
    itm1.click()
```

I get the error:

> Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="submenu1"]/a[2]"}

My question is, how can I get the right xPath of the element or any other way to access the element?

**UPDATE:**
This might be important, the issue with
`Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression` (and I've tried all proposed solutions) might be that this is after authenticate in the webpage (User + Pwd) before, everything works.
I noticed that the url `driver.current_url` after login is static (*asp* page).
Also this part I am trying to access in a frameset and **frame**

`html > frameset > frameset > frame:nth-child(1)`

Comment: Is the element inside an iframe? You may also have to wait for it to be available.

Comment: can you share the website url?

Comment: Try this xpath `//div[@id='submenu1']//a[2]`

Comment: @JeffC it is not inside an iFrame but rather  a <frameset ... <frame name = "menu" ..

Comment: You will need to switch to the frame then. You should be able to find some sample code. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Yes JeffC, it must be that. Many thanks for the tip. I am exploring it.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @JeffC to point me in the right direction.

since the page has some frames, I manage to access the element first by switching to the right frame (using xPath)
and then access the element.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('html / frameset / frameset / frame[1]'))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'PInt')]").click()
```

BTW, in case you want to run the script from a **crontab**,you need to setup a display:

```
30 5 * * * export DISPLAY=:0; python /usr/.../main.py
```

Answer (score 1):

To see a full list of all the ways of selecting elements using selenium, you can read all about it in the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Using xpath:

```
res = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'//*[@id="submenu1"]/a[2]')
```

Using css selector:

```
res = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#submenu1 a:nth-of-type(2)')
```

Comment: @Algina - I fixed a mistake with my css selector. Give that a try. Regarding the xpath, the error you're getting would mean that the element with the given xpath doesn't exist or the xpath isn't correct.

Comment: Thanks Onel. It's the same error: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#submenu1 a:nth-of-type(2)"}` Perhaps the page is somehow protected against this things... It's a 'secure' page..

Comment: Try one more thing. Select and click the main menu, and when the menu items show up, select and click the element you want to click. Let me know if that works - @Algina

Answer (score 1):

Try with any of the below xpath. Sometimes automatically generated xpath does not work.

```
//a[contains(text(),'PInt')]
or
//div[@id='submenu1']//a[contains(text(),'PInt')]
```

Also I would suggest you to set some wait time before clicking on above link in case if above xpath does not work

Comment: Try this as well `//div[@id='submenu1']//following::a[contains(text(),'PInt')]`

Comment: unfortunately any of the solutions works. Not sure how but might be the page preventing some scraping?

Answer (score 0):

To find xPath in chrome:

1. Right click the element you want
2. Inspect, which will open the developer window and highlight the selected element.
3. Right click the highlighted element and choose copy > copy by xpath

Here is a list of all the different ways to locate an element [Locating Elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and git the xPath: //[@id="submenu1"]/a[2] that somehow seems to be invalid